# pkttyagent doesn't seem to work for virt-manager over ssh -X?

Tags: ssh, fedora, libvirt

TL;DR: I seem to be too stupid to use PolKit authentication over ssh?

---

I have two machines (running Fedora) with ssh public-key logins to a user with administrative privileges (groups e.g. `wheel`, `adm`).

When logging in locally on the “server” machine, I can run `virt-manager` to access various VM's that exist on it. However, when connecting via `ssh -X -C`*server*, I find that `virt-manager` immediately refuses to connect to the virtual machines saying that:

> Virtual Machine Manager Connection Failure (on *server*)
>
> Unable to connect to libvirt.
>
> authentication failed: polkit: polkit\56retains_authorization_after_challenge=1
>   Authorization requires authentication but no agent is available.

I've tried the naïve approach of launching it like this:

```
 virt-manager & pkttyagent -p $(pgrep virt-manager)
```

… but all I'm left with is:

- `pkttyagent` is silent;
- `virt-manager` exits as soon as I close the error dialog box.

Can anyone suggest a way to, perhaps, register `pkttyagent` prior to running `virt-manager`, or else register another authentication agent over `ssh -X`?

→ It should be noted that running `virt-manager` as `root` remotely isn't even an option (effectively) because I have VM's that run under my own user account (`qemu` user-mode, accessible via Gnome Boxes) as well as system-wide ones, and the local-user definitions aren't accessible by `root`. Even if I didn't fear the idea of running an X app as `root` in the first place…

Answer (score 2):

This command worked on my system:

```
virt-manager ; pkttyagent --process $(pgrep virt-manager)
```

Comment: That's something I'd tried (with the `&` rather than `;` to allow it to run in background), but did not seem to work…

Comment: There's a different between & and ;. The ; is in my case the correct way. Do you get by the way an error message when using ;?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running a graphical agent? For example, `lxpolkit`, `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`, or `polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1`.

Alternatively, you could write a polkit rule that would remove the authentication requirement, either for a specific user or for 'wheel' members.

---

(Note that 'adm' does *not* normally mean "administrative privileges"; it means access to system logs and accounting data.)

Comment: (:facepalm:) I had tried this, but I misinterpreted the error messages it spouts. `/usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` moans about failing to connect to a DBus socket — but, it I *background* it and then run `virt-manager`, it *does* in fact work. Apparently the WARNING it prints is related to a11y, and there's no positive indication that it worked regardless. **edit** maaaybe. It seems to hang before allowing me to enter a password, but it may just be *super* slow for some reason.